# Package for simple USB web camera in groovy?

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which package is recommended to use in groovy for a web camera? And how do I install it? I seem to remember there being a package called usb_cam but I cannot find that anymore.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57320/package-for-simple-usb-web-camera-in-groovy?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nothing specific about Groovy, but here's a good overview of most of the available [USB camera drivers](http://answers.ros.org/question/9089/what-driver-should-i-use-for-my-usb-camera/).

An up-to-date list of all Ubuntu packages available for Groovy is [here](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/groovy.html). At the moment, it says camera_umd is available (green) on Oneiric and Precise, but not Quantal (red).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-03-06**:
Well, I cannot find any of them in my groovy installation (full desktop).

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-06**:
I don't think full desktop installs any drivers. You can look for ros-groovy-DRIVERNAME packages to install, or else build them from source.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-03-06**:
OK, good to know that this is the method. In groovy I seem to never know if I just is missing a deb or if I am supposed to build from source.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-03-06**:
if there is a deb and you do not want to change anything -> use the deb
if there is no deb or you want to change the code -> checkout git repo and build from source

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've used [uvc_camera](http://ros.org/wiki/uvc_camera) not that long ago, although I can't recall if it was under Groovy or not. It appears that the stack containing uvc_camera is building on Groovy, for all except 12.10 (probably an issue with the more stringent compiler). You should be able to install with "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-camera-umd" unless you are on 12.10.

usb_cam was part of bosch_drivers, which has not been released into Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-07**:
I don't see an Ubuntu package for uvc_camera, but there is a ros-groovy-camera-umd available.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-03-07**:
Thanks Jack, I had reversed the "camera" and "umd" in the stack name. Fixed above.